# ajax function is not returning expected output

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

controller is returning :

```
return Json(new { html = "<html><body>HELLO</body></html>" },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

which is simply a string 'HELLO'

my json function is as follows :

```
function callPrint() {
        var PrintCssContent = "";

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetHtmlString", "Itinerary", new { area = "Travel" })',
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);

                WinPrint.document.write(data);
                WinPrint.document.write(DivMainContent.innerHTML.toString());
                WinPrint.document.write("</body></html>");
                WinPrint.document.close();
                WinPrint.focus();
                WinPrint.print();
                WinPrint.close();
            },
            error:function(){
                alert('error');
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

but json alert is returning something like this : 
{"html":"\u003chtml\u003e\u003cbody\u003eHELLO\u003c/body\u003e\u003c/html\u003e"}

how to simply return 'HELLO' using my json function?

Comment: sorry it's AJAX function

Comment: to return only "HELLO", you should return a json with `html` equal to "HELLO". You have it wrapped in HTML tags. Use `data.html` further

Comment: i'll be returning whole html page from my mvc controller ActionResult. so first i am trying to return 
    return Json(new { html = "<html><body>HELLO</body></html>" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

for testing purpose only.

Comment: One tip I can give is write the output in console. Both firefox and chrome provides logs with detailed view. You can easily understand what you are getting from ajax response. Ex - console.log(data);

Comment: if i remove alert(parseData.html); instead of displaying data in alert box i want to print it using window.print then how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `JSON.Parse` to return the JSON data. Change your `alert` statement as,

```
 var parseData = JSON.parse(data);
 alert(parseData.html);
```

Hope this helps!.

Comment: it's returning : [object Object]

Comment: he doesn't need parsing here. He has a JSON with a field containg HTML markup, so he just needs `data.html` to be appended

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers But his JSON (as he mentioned here) has unicode characters in it. `{"html":"\u003chtml\u003e\u003cbody\u003eHELLO\u003c/body\u003e\u003c/html\u003e"}` for which we need to parse it before displaying it.

Comment: @rohit Updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: yes u r right , i have to parse the unicode characters. let me check ur solution.

Comment: @DavidR if i remove alert(parseData.html); instead of displaying data in alert box i want to print it using window.print then how can i achieve this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124404/discussion-between-david-r-and-rohit).

Comment: Glad to hear! Cool

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the result to json, then print it out, here is the code:

```
function callPrint() {
    var PrintCssContent = "";

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetHtmlString", "Itinerary", new { area = "Travel" })',
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (data) {
            var dataParsed = JSON.parse(data);
            WinPrint.document.write("<html><body>");
            WinPrint.document.write(dataParsed.html);
            // WinPrint.document.write(DivMainContent.innerHTML.toString());
            WinPrint.document.write("</body></html>");
            WinPrint.document.close();
            WinPrint.focus();
            WinPrint.print();
            WinPrint.close();
        },
        error:function(){
            alert('error');
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: it's returning 'undefined'

Comment: weird, try data['html'] or
 data[0].html // Unlikely
last idea is to 
var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
alert(parsedData.html)

Comment: if i remove alert(parseData.html); instead of displaying data in alert box i want to print it using window.print then how can i achieve this?